# Canon MG2922 cannot get to work

Tags: drivers, printing, canon

I have a Canon MG2922 printer that I want get working on an Ubuntu 14.04 desktop installation.

I would seem that none of the drivers I tried for it work. When I load them and attempt a test page, it says "Processing', the printer flashes, but nothing happens.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score -1):

http://support-asia.canon-asia.com/contents/ASIA/EN/0100626502.html
Follow the instructions you still may not be able to scan I'm still working on that myself

Comment: Good News! have figured out that in order to use the scanner you need to install scangear mp once done goto cli and type scangearmp2 and it should run

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.